# module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'tf'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

While running an old script, after updating keras and tensorflow, I faced the following error:

```
    module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'tensorflow_backend'
```

For the following line of code

```
    print(K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus())
```

I come to understand that this could be issue of **version mismatches**. The corresponding versions of **Keras** and **Tensorflow** are

```
    2.4.3
    2.2.0
    python - 3.7.5
```

What is the right version compatibiltiy / combination that I should make use of, to overcome this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()` is not available in tensorflow 2.0.

Your best bet is to use [`tf.config.list_physical_devices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/list_physical_devices) or [`tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)

```py
GPU_list = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
# OR
GPU_list = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Comment: The above command return null for me. Does this mean that the GPU is not picked up? @Chase

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan yes tensorflow is not detecting your GPU. Make sure your GPU is actually supported. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402409/tensorflow-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-gpu

Comment: so you suggest using a lower version? I remember working it once, using tf = 1.10 and Cudnn 9 with python 3.6.3

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I do not suggest using a legacy version like tensorflow 1.0. That would be ignoring the issue at hand rather than acknowledging it. As I said, make sure your GPU is supported

Answer (score 1):

you have TensorFlow wrong version

install
TensorFlow Core v2.2.0
Python

this version contains tf.keras.backend.backend()

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend

I hope this is help

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem, OP is looking for `tensorflow_backend` inside `keras.backend`, they already have tensorflow 2.0