# GPU is not recognized

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running on linux 18.04 with GPU:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e82 (rev a1)
```

nvidia-smi gives:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.119.03   Driver Version: 450.119.03   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I have python 3.6 with the following packages:

```
pip freeze |grep tensor:
tensorboard==2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow==2.4.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.4.0
tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1
```

When running the following command:

```
len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

I'm getting 0 GPUs

According to:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu it seems that the versions are correct.

I have tried to look here:

[Tensorflow doesn't seem to see my gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402409/tensorflow-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-gpu)

(reinstall tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu)- but didn't find correct solution.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you let us know the steps that you have followed to install tensorflow?