# Incompatibility issue when installing tensorflow in conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I was trying to install tensorflow in a new conda environment, but I met an incompatibility issue.

First, I use `conda search tensorflow-gpu -c conda-forge` to search available packages, and the return is

[image]

Then, I use command `conda create -n tf27 python=3.8 tensorflow-gpu=2.7.0 -c conda-forge` to install version 2.7.0, but I met the error below

[image]

conda information:
[image]

Comment: I just figured out how to get this working on my machine https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809780/125507

Comment: Please don't post images of console output. Always copy paste it into your question and put it into appropriate formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can check all available packages in anaconda by using the below code in the `anaconda prompt`:

```
 conda list
```

To install `TensorFlow` in the anaconda environment:

```
conda install pip

#If you require the latest pip
pip install --upgrade pip

#To install current stable release of TensorFlow for CPU and GPU
pip install tensorflow       
pip install tenosrflow-gpu
```

You can also specify the version you want to install as below:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.7      
pip install tenosrflow-gpu==2.7
```

To install the latest version of `TensorFlow`

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

As a reference, please follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#conda) document for installing `TensorFlow` in anaconda. Also check this [Tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) to find the compatible `TensorFlow` version for CPU and GPU support in your system.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The reason that I was trying to install Tensorflow using conda instead of pip is conda can help me automatically install dependencies such as cuda to my environment for gpu support. Otherwise, I have to install cuda drivers manually to my system. I have multiple tf versions on my computer, which needs differently versions of cuda accordingly. If I manually install cuda driver to my system, I can only keep one version.